# What is the significance of the coin and gem spaces on the board?

Tags: near-and-far

There are spaces with coin and gem icons (most of them have this).  What is the significance of these spaces?  Do I collect one of each of these items as I move through these spaces?  I don't see reference to it in the rules, so a mention of where these rules are would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please create a tag wiki for [near-and-far] so that it doesn't get purged?

Answer (score 3):

From Page 24:

> When a player builds a camp on a space with a coin or a gem symbol, the player gains gems or coins equal to the number of search symbols in the player's active party.